# Pygame frames loop

Tags: python, loops, pygame, frames, gravity

I'm making my first game at pygame. It's a Flappy Bird style game. Now I have to make gravity but I don't know how to do a for that each frame descreases the y position to the object.
For the moment my code is:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import time
import os
width = 950
height = 500
Screen = 0 # 0 = Playscreen | 1 = Game screen | 2 = Game Over screen


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Dog')
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Background_00.png")).convert()
    FlappyDog = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Flappy.png")).convert_alpha()
    Play = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Play.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog0.png")).convert_alpha()
    Dog1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Dog1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeUp1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeUp1.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown0 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown0.png")).convert_alpha()
    SpikeDown1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "SpikeDown1.png")).convert_alpha()
    GameOver = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Game-Over.png")).convert_alpha()
    Replay = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "Replay.png")).convert_alpha()

    if  Screen == 0:   
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(Dog1, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Gravity is just some force pushing down on your objects every frame, so the thought in your example is correct except you should add ”+” instead of subtract. The y-axle starts at the top in pygame, and most game engines :)

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, but i don't know how to do a for bucle that in each frame decreases the y position.

Comment: Hello! What is `frame()` in your example?

Comment: @Valentino, That is what I want to know. frame() in my example is for each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Loop

As far as I know, there is nothing in pygame such `frames()` which gives you an iterator of the frames usable with a `for` loop. You need to use the `while` loop. In the body of the loop you do all the calculations, move the surfaces, blit them on the screen, and draw. So each iteration of the loop is a "frame" (I think the term *frame* is not suitable in this case, it's not a movie with a sequence of images).

#### A note on gravity

Gravity is a force, or an acceleration (assuming you do not care about masses). In your code, you are treating it like a velocity, moving the object at a costant pace each iteration. If you want to model your gravity realistically, you need to increase the velocity with time, so that the speed due to the gravity increases according to the [uniform acceleration law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration).

#### A *very basic* example to give you the idea.

This code reproduces a free fall:

```
gravity = 2 #or whatever constant value you want for the gravity acceleration
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y)) #x and y here is the resolution
while True:
    object.time += 1
    gravity_speed = gravity * object.time
    object.rect.y += gravity_speed
    screen.blit(object.image, object.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50) #add a delay before the next loop, otherwise things happens really fast.
```

This code does not work as it is, stuffs are missing, like drawing the screen background, creating the `object` instance, which should be an instance of some sprite subclass, and also blitting again the background at previous position of `object`, or a way to break the loop.
`object.time` should be reset to `0` each time the object lands on a surface preventing him to fall down.
Note also that `object` should be instance of a class created by you (likely a child class of [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)) so you can implement your own attributes (like `time`, no class has it if you do not create it) and methods.

The fact is that you have the implement the physics in the game. pygame does not do it for you.

Also, the [pygame intro tutorial](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html) and the [Sprite tutorial](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) may be a good read.

Comment: I know. I said it in the answer: the code does not work as it is, more things should be implemented, but are unrelated to the question so I did not provide a full working code which will be longer and too broad.  But the one I posted should give you an idea of how you should go on.